# How to solve this Serialization exception?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I have my code here, I can't understand what is the bug in this.
Someone told me the problem is when Deserializing the 'Net' object in the 'Handle Client' method. Because I override it every time a new client comes in. Can you help me solve this? I still can't figure out what should I do.

At first it works for 2-3 messages and then it crashes.

The exception I get is:

Serialization Exception - The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: FF-FF-FF-FF-06-44-61-76-69-64-3A-20-66-75-63-6B-20 ... .

Also one time I got the same Serialization Exception only it said - on top object.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using Message;

namespace Chat
{
    public partial class ChatWindow : Form
    {
    uMessage umsg = new uMessage();
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    NetworkStream Net;
    TcpListener listener;
    TcpClient client;
    List<NetworkStream> Clients = new List<NetworkStream>();

    public ChatWindow(string ip, int port)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        umsg.IP = ip;
        umsg.Port = port;
    }

    public void OpenNewThread()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(umsg.IP), umsg.Port); 
        listener.Start();
        Thread a = new Thread(Listen);
        a.Start();
    }

    public void Listen()
    {
        do
        {
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Net = client.GetStream();
            Clients.Add(Net);
            umsg.Name = bf.Deserialize(Net).ToString();
            lstboxCurrentUsers.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                lstboxCurrentUsers.Items.Add($"{umsg.Name} connected at " + DateTime.Now);
                listboxHistory.Items.Add($"{umsg.Name} connected at " + DateTime.Now);
            }));
            LetSubsKnow(Clients);


                Thread b = new Thread(() => HandleClient(Clients));
                b.Start();


        } while (true);
    }

    public void HandleClient(List<NetworkStream> ClientsStream)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            umsg.Message = bf.Deserialize(Net).ToString();

            foreach (var client in ClientsStream)
                {
                   bf.Serialize(client, umsg.Message);
                }
        }
    }

    public void LetSubsKnow(List<NetworkStream> clientsStream)
    {           
        foreach (var client in clientsStream)
        {
            bf.Serialize(client, $"{umsg.Name} Has Connected.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your code is thread safe.

Comment: I wouldn't use `BinaryFormatter` to serialize `string`s, it adds extra payload, is harder to debug and is not compatible with non-.NET clients. You might want to use `Encoding.UTF8` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `Net` field keeps getting replaced by the client that has most recently connected, so even though you have one `HandleClient` thread per client, all these threads read from the most recently obtained `NetworkStream`.

Similarly the `umsg.Name` field is overwritten whenever a client connects, and the `umsg.Message` field whenever a message arrives.

You can fix these issues by supplying the `NetworkStream` of the individual connection to `HandleClient`, and creating a local variable for the received message:

```
public void HandleClient(NetworkStream client)
{
    ...
    string message = bf.Deserialize(client).ToString();
    ...
}
```

Similarly you will need to pass the name of the client to the `LetSubsKnow` method, instead of relying on the `umsg` field that keeps getting updated.

```
public void LetSubsKnow(string clientName)
{
    ....
}
```

Furthermore even though you *pass* the `clientsStream` around as a parameter, they are all the same reference to the `Clients` field, and if a client connects *while* you're sending data, the `foreach` will throw a "The collection has been modified" exception.

This can be fixed by accessing the `Clients` field using a lock. I wouldn't put the whole `foreach` block inside a lock section, but take a snapshot of the currently connected clients instead:

```
private readonly object clientsLock = new object();
List<NetworkStream> Clients = new List<NetworkStream>();
...
NetworkStream[] currentClients;
lock(clientsLock)
{
    currentClients = Clients.ToArray();
}

foreach (NetworkStream client in currentClients)
{
    // send stuff
}
```

Note that you're going to need some exception handling around the `NetworkStream` accessing code.

Last but not least I don't think `BinaryFormatter` is thread-safe (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453667/292411)). Instead of locking you might be better off creating new ones in the `HandleClient` and `LetSubsKnow` methods.